# How to strip all parameters and the domain name from a URL using javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, url

Given a series of URLs

```
http://www.anydotcom.com/myfolder/some-url.html
http://www.anydotcom.com/myfolder2/index.html#
http://www.anydotcom.com/myfolder3/index.html?someParam=aValue
http://www.anydotcom.com/foldername/index.html?someParam=anotherValue
```

First, how could I strip anything off the end of the URL so that I end up with

```
http://www.anydotcom.com/myfolder/some-url.html
http://www.anydotcom.com/myfolder2/index.html
http://www.anydotcom.com/myfolder3/index.html
http://www.anydotcom.com/foldername/index.html
```

or, ideally, I would like it to return

```
/myfolder/some-url.html
/myfolder2/index.html
/myfolder3/index.html
/foldername/index.html
```

I've tried

```
    var thisUrl = "" + window.location;
    var myRegExp = new RegExp("([^(\?#)]*)");
    thisUrl = myRegExp.exec(thisUrl);
```

but this returns

```
http://www.anydotcom.com/foldername/index.html,http://www.anydotcom.com/foldername/index.html
```

and I don't quite understand why.

I appreciate any help here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `window.location`, you can simply access the wanted data by using:

```
var thisUrl = window.location.pathname;
```

If you are extracting stuff from links, the following regular expression will get you what you need:

```
// Supports all protocols (file, ftp, http, https, whatever)
var pathExtract = /^[a-z]+:\/\/\/?[^\/]+(\/[^?]*)/i;
var thisUrl = (pathExtract.exec(someUrl))[1];
```

Comment: Ugh. That's what I get for not completely checking out the location object. Thank you for the quick answer.

Answer (score 2):

Well, to answer your question directly, here's the regular expression to do that.

```
thisUrl = thisUrl.replace( /^https?:\/\/[^\/]|\?.*$/g, '' );
```

However, since you mention window.location in your code, you can actually get this data straight from the [location object](http://www.w3schools.com/HTMLDOM/dom_obj_location.asp).

```
thisUrl = top.location.pathname;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my original question first before showing me the error of my ways! I definitely need to start researching existing properties of an object before trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: That regex is removing the first character.

Answer (score 0):

[Javascript location object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

```
var loc = window.location;
var thisUrl = loc.protocol + "//" + loc.hostname + loc.pathname;
```

Answer (score 0):

using the object window.location is simple as write:

```
function getPath() {
    return window.location.pathname;
}
```